# Prove: Any prime of the form $3n+1$ is also in the form $6m+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that any prime of the form $3n+1$ is also in the form $6m+1$.

So first I found an example... $3(2)+1=7$ and $6(1)+1=7 $. How do I go about a formal proof though?

Answer (score 7):

If $3n+1$ is a prime, and as it is $>2$ [$2$ is the only prime even number, and that it has not the form 3n+1],
 $n$ is even.

Let $n=2m$. Then $3n+1 = 6m+1$.

Comment: do you know 3n+1 is odd because its written in the form 2k+1?

Comment: no, because $2$ is the only prime even number, and that it has not the form $3n+1$.

Answer (score 3):

It's well known fact that every prime number, expect for $2$ and $3$ is of the form $6n \pm 1$. It's easy to prove using contradiction.

Assume the contrary. Let $p=6k-1=3n + 1$

Work modulo $3$ and you should get:

$$-1 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

A contradiction. Hence the proof.

Another way is to check both cases $p \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $p\equiv 1 \pmod 2$. Use Chinese remainder and you'll get for the first case that $p = 6k + 4$, clearly not a prime. Now you need to check the second case.

EDIT:

A little late, but here's the proof for the initial claim. Checking the remaining cases we have:

$$6k + 2 = 2(3k + 1)$$
$$6k + 3 = 3(2k + 1)$$
$$6k + 4 = 2(3k + 2)$$

Since $k$ is natural numbers it's clear that these numbers are composite. $6k$ is trivial. Hence the proof.

Comment: at this level, it would be nice to include a justification for the $6n+1$ claim.

Comment: @robjohn I don't quite understand your point.

Comment: It may be a "well known fact" at some level, but at an introductory level, it might be useful to prove that every prime number except $2$ and $3$ is of the form $6n\pm1$.

Comment: @robjohn I've added some explanation. Is it better now?

Comment: I think it might be better for the OP now.